# How to get the WebApplicationType of Springboot application at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library that I use in reactive and non-reactive spring-boot applications. How can I within my library find out at runtime whether the application is REACTIVE or SERVLET?

Comment: See my answer, if you have any comment, let's tell me!

Comment: You can inject the `ApplicationContext` and detect if it is an `org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebApplicationContext` which means it is a reactive application. Check the `WebApplicationType` enum from Spring Boot how the detection works (sadly the methods are package private so unusable from within your code).